# mirrors.jenkins-ci.org does not respond

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins plugins updates portal does not work:
https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/job-dsl/1.77/job-dsl.hpi

It looks that some mirrors.jenkinsci.org stopped working:

```
wget https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/job-dsl/1.77/job-dsl.hpi
--2020-06-03 06:17:55--  https://updates.jenkins.io/download/plugins/job-dsl/1.77/job-dsl.hpi
Resolving updates.jenkins.io (updates.jenkins.io)... 52.202.51.185
Connecting to updates.jenkins.io (updates.jenkins.io)|52.202.51.185|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/job-dsl/1.77/job-dsl.hpi [following]
--2020-06-03 06:17:56--  http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/job-dsl/1.77/job-dsl.hpi
Resolving mirrors.jenkins-ci.org (mirrors.jenkins-ci.org)... 52.202.51.185
Connecting to mirrors.jenkins-ci.org (mirrors.jenkins-ci.org)|52.202.51.185|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

and

```
wget http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org
--2020-06-03 06:21:37--  http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/
Resolving mirrors.jenkins-ci.org (mirrors.jenkins-ci.org)... 52.202.51.185
Connecting to mirrors.jenkins-ci.org (mirrors.jenkins-ci.org)|52.202.51.185|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

## jenkins

Answer (score 1):

The Jenkins project infrastructure is mainly maintained by a group of contributors, you can have more information [here](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/infrastructure/), when you experience issues with one of the services it's usually better to send a message on the Jenkins infra mailing list [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jenkins-infra).

More specifically with the update center, you can use this [dashboard](https://p.datadoghq.com/sb/0Igb9a-718db6e2d01b5962c91bf45bf50183ff) to see the current response time, most of the time that service is just overloaded, they are plans to work on the mirroring infrastructure as you can see in the Jenkins [roadmap](https://www.jenkins.io/project/roadmap/)